# List of Algorithms Using algorithm2e

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithm2e

According to the documentation, I can add an entry in the ToC for the list of algorithms created using the `algorithm2e` package by including `dotocloa` as a package option. When I do this I receive an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1005 \newcommand{\algocf@name
                               }{algorithm2e}%
```

How can I fix it so List of Algorithms appears in the ToC?

Here is a minimum non-working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[dotocloa]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

\begin{algorithm} 
\caption{AlgorithmName}\label{alg:AlgorithmName}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It *is* a bug in the package; line 1001 should be `}{}` instead of `}`. There's no fix possible other than editing the file or bypassing the `dotocloa` option Ian Thompson suggests. Contact the package author.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the package. I think there might be some confusion between 'algorithms' and 'algorithmes' (which is presumably the French spelling). This hack seems to work though.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\newcommand{\listofalgorithmes}{\tocfile{\listalgorithmcfname}{loa}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofalgorithmes

\chapter{Test}

\begin{algorithm} 
\caption{AlgorithmName}\label{alg:AlgorithmName}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```